# How to remove 3 last numbers, seperated by space, in each line of a file - and remove everything exept said three numbers

Tags: sed, awk, list

I need to split a file containing data of this type;

```
Jazz Guitar 1 16 3 4
Carlos Guitar1 16 3 5
Overdrive Gtr1 16 3 6
Western Gtr&Whis 16 3 7
Pat Guitar Synth 16 3 8
Shadow Guitar 16 3 9
Clean El.Guitar 16 3 10
Overdrive Gtr2 16 3 11
```

into 2 file - one containing only the 3 last numbers - and one containing everything before these, as below;

```
16 3 4
16 3 5
16 3 6
16 3 7
16 3 8
16 3 9
16 3 10
16 3 11
```

and

```
Jazz Guitar 1
Carlos Guitar1
Overdrive Gtr1
Western Gtr&Whis
Pat Guitar Synth
Shadow Guitar
Clean El.Guitar
Overdrive Gtr2
```

SED, AWK or similar commands will be appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `cut` to select columns, combine it with `rev` to count from the right:

```
rev file | cut -d' ' -f1,2,3 | rev > file1
rev file | cut -d' ' -f4-    | rev > file2
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU awk:

```bsh
gawk '{print $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF > "file1"; NF -= 3; print > "file2"}' input
```

"file1" will contain the last 3 columns.
"file2" will contain the initial columns.

Works with `mawk` as well. For the default awk on MacOS, you have to do

```
/usr/bin/awk '{
    print $(NF-2), $(NF-1), $NF > "file1"
    $(NF-2) = ""; $(NF-1) = ""; $NF  = ""
    print > "file2"
}' input
```